# Twitter Get Function

Tags: php, search, twitter, get

I'm trying to perfect my Twitter bot, and I'm stuck with this one issue that's been bugging me for a while. Basically, whenever I try to execute this code:

```
<?

$consumerKey    = '------';
$consumerSecret = '------';
$oAuthToken     = '------';
$oAuthSecret     = '------';

include "OAuth.php";
include "twitteroauth.php";

$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

    echo "Your message has not been sent to Twitter.";
$twitter->host = "http://search.twitter.com/";
$search = $twitter -> get('search', array('q' => 'pool -table -TowlieBot -#pool :)', 'rpp' => 15));

$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";
foreach($search->results as $tweet) {
    $tweet->post('statuses/update',array('status' => '@'.$tweet->from_user.': Don\'t forget to bring a towel.'));
}
?>
```

I get a **Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::get() on line 16**.

Here's the get function I used:

```
function get($url, $parameters = array()) {
    $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'GET', $parameters);
    if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
    }
    return $response;
```

Comment: I hope those aren't your actual keys at the top there!

Comment: Oh shieeeeee-

Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Haha, no worries mate, only 16 views so far :-D

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different variables for your `TwitterOAuth` object - `$tweet` and `$twitter`. Try picking just one:

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

echo "Your message has not been sent to Twitter.";
$twitter->host = "http://search.twitter.com/";
$search = $twitter -> get('search', array('q' => 'pool -table -TowlieBot -#pool :)', 'rpp' => 15));
```